How to show Current label infront of a record in lwc tree?
How to show "Current" label in the lightning-tree-grid. The below snapshot is from the OOB Account Hierarchy
which attribute can I use?
I am referring to this code
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-tree-grid/example
<lightning-tree-grid
            columns={gridColumns}
            data={gridData}
            key-field="name"
        ></lightning-tree-grid>

Here is my js code
export const COLUMNS_DEFINITION_BASIC = [
    {
        type: 'text',
        fieldName: 'accountName',
        label: 'Account Name',
    },
    {
        type: 'phone',
        fieldName: 'phone',
        label: 'Phone Number',
    },
];

/**
 * Columns definition
 * :: with non-whitelisted column keys
 */
export const COLUMNS_DEFINITION_NONWHITELIST = [
    {
        type: 'text',
        fieldName: 'accountName',
        label: 'Account Name',
    },
    {
        type: 'phone',
        fieldName: 'phone',
        label: 'Phone Number',
        sortable: true,
    },
];

/**
 * Columns definition
 * :: used in examples
 */
export const EXAMPLES_COLUMNS_DEFINITION_BASIC = [
    {
        type: 'text',
        fieldName: 'accountName',
        label: 'Account Name',
        initialWidth: 300,
    },
    {
        type: 'number',
        fieldName: 'employees',
        label: 'Employees',
    },
    {
        type: 'phone',
        fieldName: 'phone',
        label: 'Phone Number',
    },
    {
        type: 'url',
        fieldName: 'accountOwner',
        label: 'Account Owner',
        typeAttributes: {
            label: { fieldName: 'accountOwnerName' },
        },
    },
    {
        type: 'text',
        fieldName: 'billingCity',
        label: 'Billing City',
    },
];



Which attribute have you tried to use?

Updated my code @NickC

Lightning tree grid does not seem to allow slds-badge within the rows content (there may exist a solution without using Lightning tree grid but this will require more digging).
A simpler workaround by still using lightning-tree-grid is to display an icon conditionally in cellAttributes to identify the current record.
Sample code below queries simple account hierarchy based on current account, adapt the code accordingly to display deeper level hierarchies.
Apex class
public with sharing class AccountHierarchyController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> getAccountHierarchy(String recordId, String parentId) {
        List<Account> listAcc = new List<Account>();
        for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, 
                    (SELECT Id, Name,ParentId FROM ChildAccounts )
                FROM Account 
                WHERE Id =:parentId
                WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED]){
            listAcc.add(acc);                 
        }

        if(listAcc.size() == 0 ){
            for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name, ParentId, 
            (SELECT Id, Name,ParentId FROM ChildAccounts)
                FROM Account 
                WHERE Id =:recordId
                WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED]){
            listAcc.add(acc);                 
        }
        }
        return listAcc;
    }
}

JS
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccountHierarchy from '@salesforce/apex/AccountHierarchyController.getAccountHierarchy';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import PARENT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.ParentId';

export default class AccountHierarchyGrid extends LightningElement {
    @track gridData = [];
    @api recordId;

    @track columns = [
        {
            type: 'text',
            fieldName: 'Name',
            label: 'Account Name',
            cellAttributes: {
                iconName: { fieldName: 'isCurrent' },
                iconPosition: 'right'
            }
        }
    ];

    @wire(getRecord, { 
        recordId: '$recordId',
        fields: [
            PARENT_FIELD
        ]
    })
    account;

    get parentId() {
        return getFieldValue(this.account.data, PARENT_FIELD);
    }

    @wire(getAccountHierarchy , 
        { recordId: '$recordId',
          parentId: '$parentId'
         })
    wiredAccounts({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.gridData = this.processAccountHierarchy(data);
            // console.log('this.gridData = ' +JSON.stringify(this.gridData));
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching account hierarchy', error);
        }
    }

    processAccountHierarchy(accounts) {
        //Child Relationship Name returned is ChildAccounts with C uppercase 
       return accounts.map(account => ({
            ...account,
            isCurrent: account.Id === this.recordId 
                        ? 'action:approval'
                        : '',
            _children: account.ChildAccounts ? account.ChildAccounts.map(child => ({ ...child,  
                isCurrent: child.Id === this.recordId 
                ? 'action:approval': ''})) : []
        }));
    }
}

HTML
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Account Hierarchy">
        <lightning-tree-grid
            columns={columns}
            data={gridData}
            key-field="Id"
            hide-checkbox-column>
        </lightning-tree-grid>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>62.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

Child account is current record :

Parent account is current record:


Thanks  @shamina it works like a charm!!!
